# ¿Se puede cambiar el estilo de un botón o de un input al cargar una tabla con datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy realizando un botón que selecciona/deselecciona todos los botones que se encuentran en un datatable. Su estilo está condicionado a que estén todos los elementos seleccionados o no de la datatable. Por ejemplo, si están todos seleccionados debe aparecer así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hay alguno sin seleccionar (o ninguno seleccionado), debe verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
    //Contamos todos los activos para una mejor gestión de los eventos
function contadorActivos() {
    var totalFilasTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().rows()[0].length;
    var contadorActivos = 0;
    for (var contador = 0; contador < totalFilasTabla; contador++) {

        var botonActualTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contador].firstChild;

        if (botonActualTabla.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
            contadorActivos += 1;
        }


    }
    if (contadorActivos !== totalFilasTabla) {
        $("#botonSeleccion").className = 'btn seleccionar click'
    }
    if (contadorActivos === totalFilasTabla && !$("#botonSeleccion").hasClass("activo")) {
        $("#botonSeleccion").addClass("activo");
    } 

}

function allCheckUnCheck(btn) {
//var elementoBuscador = $("input[type=search]").val();
clicarUltimo();

var totalFilas = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().rows()[0].length;
var columnas = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes();





if (btn.className == 'btn seleccionar click') {
    for (var contClic = 0; contClic < totalFilas; contClic++) {

        var botonActual = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contClic].firstChild;

        if (botonActual.className == 'btn seleccionar click') {
            var rescrointActual = crotales[contClic].rescroint;
            clikadoCrotal(botonActual, rescrointActual);
        }


    }
    btn.className = 'btn seleccionar click activo';
} else if (btn.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
    for (var contTotal = 0; contTotal < totalFilas; contTotal++) {
        var hayBotonActualTotal = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contTotal]
        if (hayBotonActualTotal) {
            var botonActualTotal = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contTotal].firstChild;

            var rescroActual = crotales[contTotal].rescroint;
            if (botonActualTotal.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
                clikadoCrotal(botonActualTotal, rescroActual);
            }

        }
    }
    btn.className = 'btn seleccionar click';
}
```

}

```
//Contamos todos los activos para una mejor gestión de los eventos
function contadorActivosTablaCrotales_bis() {
    var totalFilasTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().rows()[0].length;
    var contadorActivos = 0;
    for (var contador = 0; contador < totalFilasTabla; contador++) {

        var botonActualTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contador].firstChild;

        if (botonActualTabla.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
            contadorActivos += 1;
        }


    }
    if (contadorActivos !== totalFilasTabla) {
        $("#botonSeleccion").className = 'btn seleccionar click'
    }
    if (contadorActivos === totalFilasTabla && !$("#botonSeleccion").hasClass("activo")) {
        $("#botonSeleccion").addClass("activo");
    } 

}
```

function clikadoCrotal(b, rescroint) {

```
if (b.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
    //viene de estar activo y se desactiva
    //hay que desvacunar
    b.className = 'btn seleccionar click'
    //Seleccionamos el boton de seleccion total
    var boton = $("#botonSeleccion")
    if (boton.hasClass("activo")) {
        boton.removeClass("activo");
    }
    //desvacunar crotal
    vacunarCrotal(rescroint, "false")
    cambiarValorColumna="true"
}
else {
    if (b.className == 'btn seleccionar click') {
        //mirar si hay dosis disponible
        if (modo == "A") {
            var num = numCrotalesAVacunar()
            if (num + 1 > parseInt(dosisdisponibles)) {
                $("#numcrotalesvacunados")[0].innerHTML = "<div id='name'>" + literalesPage[53735] + ":<b> " + dosisdisponibles + "</b>.<br>" + literalesPage[53752] + ":<b style='color:red;font-size:medium'> " + num + "</b></div>";
                $("#alert-dosisdisponibles").modal('show');
                cambiarValorColumna = "false"
                //alert("no hay dosis disponibles")
             } else {
                ; //viene de estar desactivado y se activa
                //hay que vacunar
                b.className = 'btn seleccionar click activo'
                //vacunar crotal
                vacunarCrotal(rescroint, "true");
                cambiarValorColumna = "true"
            };
        } else {

            if (modo == "E") {
                //miro a ver si puedo vacunar uno mas
                var vacunasAutilizar = numCrotalesAVacunar() + 1;
                if ((parseInt(dosisdisponibles) + parseInt(numresesvacunadas)) >= vacunasAutilizar) {
                    ; //viene de estar desactivado y se activa
                    //hay que vacunar
                    b.className = 'btn seleccionar click activo'
                    //vacunar crotal
                    vacunarCrotal(rescroint, "true");
                    cambiarValorColumna = "true"
                } else {
                    //no hay suficientes vacunas
                    $("#numcrotalesvacunados")[0].innerHTML = "<div id='name'>" + literalesPage[53735] + ":<b>" + (parseInt(dosisdisponibles) + parseInt(numresesvacunadas)) + "</b>.<br>" + literalesPage[53752] + ":<b style='color:red;font-size:medium'>" + vacunasAutilizar + "</b></div>";
                    $("#alert-dosisdisponibles").modal('show');
                    cambiarValorColumna = "false"
                    return false;


                };
            };
        };

       
    }
}
contadorActivos();
```

};

Todo va bien, pero hay un problema pequeña: cuando cambio de página y vuelvo a esta misma, el botón no guarda el estilo que debería. Por ejemplo, si paso a la siguiente página (o retrocedo), y no he seleccionado algún elemento, debería verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y sin embargo, se ve con el estilo contrario.

Mi datatable:

```
 var columnDefs = [
               {
                   "targets": [4],
                   "visible": false
               },
               {
                   "targets": [0],
                   //"orderDataType": 'dom-checkbox'. Añadimos un
                   "orderData": [4]
               }
        ];


        $.fn.dataTable.moment(selectedLanguageMomentDateType2);
        var tablaCrotales = $('#tabla-crotales').on('init.dt', function () {
            customColumnHeader(this.id);
            //selectedRows();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            if (contadorActivosTabla()) {
                $('#botonSeleccion').addClass("activo");
            } else {
                $("#botonSeleccion").className = 'btn seleccionar click'
            }
        })
            .DataTable({
                //"destroy": true,//1
                "data": dataSet,
                //"ordering": false,//2
                //"searching": false,//3
                "bProcessing": true,
                "paging": true,
                //"lengthChange": false,//4
                //"autoWidth": false,
                "bInfo": true, //Dont display info eg "Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries"
                //"paging": false,//Dont want paging 
                //"bPaginate": false,//Dont want paging 
                "columnDefs": columnDefs,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "scrollX": true,
                //"bServerSide":true,//5
                "deferRender": true,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "Todos"]],
                "columns": [

                    {
                        //"width":25,"<div id='name'>" + literalesPage[53739] + class='btn seleccionar click'
                        "data": null, "title": "<div id='name' >" + "<button type='button' id='botonSeleccion'  onclick='allCheckUnCheck(this);' class='btn seleccionar click'></button> " + "</div>"

                        ,
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                           
                          
                            if (full.vacunado == "true") {
                                button = '<button class="btn seleccionar click activo"  onclick="clikadoCrotal(this,\'' + isNull(data.rescroint) + '\')" type="input"></button>';
                            } else {

                                button = '<button class="btn seleccionar click"  onclick="clikadoCrotal(this,\'' + isNull(data.rescroint) + '\')" type="input"></button>';
                             
                            }
                           

                            return button;
                        },
                        

                    },
                    { "data": "crotal", "title": "<div id='name' >" + literalesPage[53723] + "</div>" },
                    {
                        "data": "fechanacimiento",
                        "title": "<div id='name'>" + literalesPage[53753] + "</div>",
                        "orderable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "fecha",
                        "title": "<div id='name'>" + literalesPage[53740] + "</div>",
                        //"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        //    var fecha;
                        //    if ((full.fecha != null)&(full.fecha != "")) {
                        //        fecha = moment(full.fecha, momentDateTypes[selectedLanguage]).format(WSMomentDateType);
                        //    };
                        //    return fecha;
                        //}, class='asc'
                        "orderable": true

                    },
                    { "data": "vacunado", "title": "<div id='name' > hidden</div>" }
                    //,
                    //{
                    //    "data": "",
                    //    // "className": 'anular',
                    //    "orderable": false,
                    //    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    //        html = "";
                    //        if (full.fecha != "") {
                    //            html = '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-anular"><i id="anular" style="color: #2567e0" class="fa fa-trash"></a>';
                    //        };class='asc'
                    //        return html;
                    //    }
                    //}

                ],
                "order": [],
                "language": {
                    "url": datatableLanguageUrl
                }

            });


        $('#tabla-crotales').on('draw.dt',
            function () {
                $('button[id^="pop"]').each(
                    function (index, button) {
                        var motivonoapto = tablaCrotales.row($(button).closest('tr')).data().motivonoapto;
                        $(button).parents('td').popover({ 'placement': 'top', 'content': motivonoapto, 'container': 'td' });
                    }
                );
                controlOrderShowHide(tablaCrotales);
               
            }
        );
       
        function contadorActivosTabla() {
            var totalFilasTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().rows()[0].length;
            var contadorActivos = 0;
            for (var contador = totalFilasTabla - 1; contador >= 0; contador--) {

                var botonActualTabla = $("#tabla-crotales").DataTable().columns().nodes()[0][contador].firstChild;

                if (botonActualTabla.className == 'btn seleccionar click activo') {
                    contadorActivos += 1;
                }


            }
            if (contadorActivos !== totalFilasTabla) {
                return false;
            }
            if (contadorActivos === totalFilasTabla) {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

¿Por qué no me funciona? He probado eventos como cargar página y sigue sin resolverse el problema.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he resuelto. Se trataba de asignar las funciones necesarias en el evento init.dt de Datatable.

```
var tablaCrotales = $('#tabla-crotales').on('init.dt', function () {
            customColumnHeader(this.id);
            //selectedRows();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            clicarTodosInicio();
            if (contadorActivosTabla()) {
                $('#botonSeleccion').addClass("activo");
            } else {
                $("#botonSeleccion").className = 'btn seleccionar click'
            }
        })
            .DataTable({
```